# Suppose that $\int_{a}^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ and show $f = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function over $[a,b]$. Further suppose that $\int_{a}^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ for all continuous functions $g$. Show that $f = 0$.

Let $g(x) = \epsilon$. Then since $\int_{a}^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$, we know that $f$ must be less than or equal to $0$ on some interval. Similarly we can show that $f$ must be greater than or equal to $0$ on some interval. How do I use this to show that $f$ must be $0$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: the fact that $f$ is continuous means that if $f(x_0)> 0$ then $f > f(x_0)/2$ on $[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon $ small enough..

Answer (score 5):

It must hold for $g=f$. In this case, $\int_a^b f^2 = 0$, whence $f^2 = 0$.